# how to copy multiple types files with x and copy

Tags: sas

I have three types of files (.csv, .sas7bdat, .txt) under C:/test. I want to copy .csv and .sas7bdat to c:/try. what should I do using x "copy..."

I tried following and it did not work:

```
x "copy c:/test/x.{.csv, .sas7bdat} c:/try/*.*"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `robocopy`. Use * if you want to wildcard many files with the extensions

```
%sysexec robocopy c:\test c:\try x.csv x.sas7bdat x.txt
%sysexec robocopy c:\test c:\try *.csv *.sas7bdat *.txt
```

Comment: `x` and `%sysexec` are essentially the same statement.  Yes `>` or `>>` can direct the OS command output to a log file or append to a log file.  There are many options and `robocopy /?` will explain them all

Comment: Many thanks. Is it possible to use x "copy"  to copy more than 1 type files?

Comment: Why settle on `copy` when you have `robocopy`?

Comment:  just wonder whether there is a way to copy 2 types of data in one line.